# Error Message: Concat function requires 2 arguments

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation

I have the following code which works fine when run as a Query but returns error message when run as view. I have attached the error message. I think I am missing a brace somewhere. If anyone can help it is much appreciated.

[image: Error Message]

```
SELECT      CASE 
                WHEN a.Sex = 1 
                    THEN 'M' 
                WHEN a.Sex = 2 
                    THEN 'F' 
            END AS Derived_Sex, 
            CASE
                WHEN concat(b.Complete, a.[CALCULATED_AGE]) LIKE 'A%' 
                    THEN 'Less than 1' 
                WHEN concat(b.Complete, a.[CALCULATED_AGE]) LIKE 'B%' 
                    THEN 'Less than 1' 
                WHEN concat(b.Complete, a.[CALCULATED_AGE]) LIKE 'C%' 
                    THEN 'Less than 1' 
                ELSE '1 year and above' 
            END AS Derived_InfantCat,
            YEAR(a.DATE_OF_DEATH) AS [Derived_Year of Death], 
            FORMAT(a.DATE_OF_DEATH, 'MM') AS [Derived_Month of Death], 
            YEAR(a.DATE_OF_REGISTRATION) AS [Derived_Year of Registration], 
            FORMAT(a.DATE_OF_REGISTRATION, 'MM') AS [Derived_Month of Registration], 
            CONCAT(LEFT(CONVERT(nvarchar, a.DATE_OF_DEATH, 21), 4), 
            SUBSTRING(CONVERT(nvarchar, a.DATE_OF_DEATH, 21), 6, 2)) AS [Derived_YearMonth of Death], 
            CONCAT(LEFT(CONVERT(nvarchar, a.DATE_OF_REGISTRATION, 21), 4), 
            SUBSTRING(CONVERT(nvarchar, a.DATE_OF_REGISTRATION, 21), 6, 2)) AS [Derived_YearMonth of Registration], 
            CASE 
                WHEN LEN(
                        CASE 
                            WHEN (a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) = '' 
                                THEN a.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
                            WHEN (a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) IS NULL 
                                THEN a.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
                            ELSE a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH 
                        END) = 3 
                THEN CONCAT(
                        CASE 
                            WHEN (a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) = '' 
                                THEN a.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
                            WHEN (a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) IS NULL 
                                THEN a.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
                            ELSE a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH 
                        END, 'X') 
                ELSE 
                        (CASE 
                            WHEN (a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) = '' 
                                THEN a.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
                            WHEN (a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) IS NULL 
                                THEN a.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
                            ELSE a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH 
                        END) 
            END AS [Derived_Cause of Death Code], 
            c.[4 character DESCRIPTION], 
            c.[3 character Sub-Chapter Description], 
            d.[District_Name] AS [LA NAME],
            e.[WD14NM] AS [WARD NAME],


            (
            CASE
                WHEN a.[NHS_ESTABLISHMENT_IND] = '1'
                    THEN 'NHS'
                WHEN  a.[NHS_ESTABLISHMENT_IND] = '2'
                    THEN 'NON-NHS'
                ELSE 'OTHER'
            END) AS [NHS ESTABLISHMENT TYPE DESCRIPTION],
            (
            CASE
                WHEN a.[NHS_ESTABLISHMENT_IND] = '1'
                    THEN 'NHS'
                WHEN  a.[NHS_ESTABLISHMENT_IND] = '2'
                    THEN 'NON-NHS'
                ELSE 'OTHER'
            END) AS [NHS ESTABLISHMENT TYPE DESCRIPTION],
            (
            CASE
                WHEN a.[NHS_ESTABLISHMENT_IND] = '1'
                    THEN 'NHS'
                WHEN  a.[NHS_ESTABLISHMENT_IND] = '2'
                    THEN 'NON-NHS'
                ELSE 'OTHER'
            END) AS [NHS ESTABLISHMENT TYPE DESCRIPTION],
            (
            CASE
                WHEN a.PLACE_OF_DEATH_CODE = 'H'
                    THEN 'HOME'
                WHEN  a.PLACE_OF_DEATH_CODE = 'E'
                    THEN 'ELSEWHERE'
                ELSE 'OTHER'
            END
            ) AS [PLACE OF DEATH CODE],
            concat(a.[NHS_ESTABLISHMENT_IND],'-',a.PLACE_OF_DEATH_CODE) as code
FROM        RAW.dbo.ONS_Death_DOD201516FYQ1 AS a 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN REFERENCE.dbo.[ONS-PCMD_AGE] AS b 
                    ON a.CALCULATED_AGE_UNIT = b.[Age Unit] 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN REFERENCE.dbo.[OTH_ICD-10] AS c 
                    ON 
                        CASE 
                            WHEN LEN(
                                    CASE 
                                        WHEN (a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) = '' 
                                            THEN a.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
                                        WHEN (a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) IS NULL 
                                            THEN a.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
                                        ELSE a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH 
                                    END) = 3 
                            THEN CONCAT
                                (
                                    CASE 
                                        WHEN (a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) = '' 
                                            THEN a.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1]
                                        WHEN (a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) IS NULL
                                            THEN a.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
                                        ELSE a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH 
                                    END, 'X') 
                             ELSE (
                                    CASE 
                                        WHEN (a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) = '' 
                                            THEN a.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
                                        WHEN (a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) IS NULL 
                                            THEN a.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
                                        ELSE a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH 
                                    END) 
                        END = c.[4 CharacterDiagnosis Code]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN REFERENCE.dbo.GEOG_LANames_1991 AS d
                        ON a.[ULA_OF_RESIDENCE_CODE]    = d.[ONS_District_Code]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN REFERENCE.dbo.GEOG_WardNames_2014 AS e
                        ON CONCAT(a.[ULA_OF_RESIDENCE_CODE],a.[WARD_OF_RESIDENCE_CODE]) =e.WD14CDO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a chance of null value in the concatenated fields. I have applied ISNULL function to the columns from the outer joined table. 
Just try with the below formatted code.

```
 SELECT      CASE 
                WHEN a.Sex = 1 
                    THEN 'M' 
                WHEN a.Sex = 2 
                    THEN 'F' 
            END AS Derived_Sex, 
            CASE
                WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(CONCAT(ISNULL(b.Complete,''), a.[CALCULATED_AGE]))) LIKE 'A%' 
                    THEN 'Less than 1' 
                WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(concat(ISNULL(b.Complete,''), a.[CALCULATED_AGE]))) LIKE 'B%' 
                    THEN 'Less than 1' 
                WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(concat(ISNULL(b.Complete,''), a.[CALCULATED_AGE]))) LIKE 'C%' 
                    THEN 'Less than 1' 
                ELSE '1 year and above' 
            END AS Derived_InfantCat,
            YEAR(a.DATE_OF_DEATH) AS [Derived_Year of Death], 
            FORMAT(a.DATE_OF_DEATH, 'MM') AS [Derived_Month of Death], 
            YEAR(a.DATE_OF_REGISTRATION) AS [Derived_Year of Registration], 
            FORMAT(a.DATE_OF_REGISTRATION, 'MM') AS [Derived_Month of Registration], 
            CONCAT(LEFT(CONVERT(nvarchar, a.DATE_OF_DEATH, 21), 4), 
            SUBSTRING(CONVERT(nvarchar, a.DATE_OF_DEATH, 21), 6, 2)) AS [Derived_YearMonth of Death], 
            CONCAT(LEFT(CONVERT(nvarchar, a.DATE_OF_REGISTRATION, 21), 4), 
            SUBSTRING(CONVERT(nvarchar, a.DATE_OF_REGISTRATION, 21), 6, 2)) AS [Derived_YearMonth of Registration], 
            CASE 
                WHEN LEN(
                        CASE 
                            WHEN (a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) = '' 
                                THEN a.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
                            WHEN (a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) IS NULL 
                                THEN a.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
                            ELSE a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH 
                        END) = 3 
                THEN CONCAT(
                        CASE 
                            WHEN (a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) = '' 
                                THEN a.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
                            WHEN (a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) IS NULL 
                                THEN a.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
                            ELSE a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH 
                        END, 'X') 
                ELSE 
                        (CASE 
                            WHEN (a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) = '' 
                                THEN a.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
                            WHEN (a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) IS NULL 
                                THEN a.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
                            ELSE a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH 
                        END) 
            END AS [Derived_Cause of Death Code], 
            c.[4 character DESCRIPTION], 
            c.[3 character Sub-Chapter Description], 
            d.[District_Name] AS [LA NAME],
            e.[WD14NM] AS [WARD NAME],


            (
            CASE
                WHEN a.[NHS_ESTABLISHMENT_IND] = '1'
                    THEN 'NHS'
                WHEN  a.[NHS_ESTABLISHMENT_IND] = '2'
                    THEN 'NON-NHS'
                ELSE 'OTHER'
            END) AS [NHS ESTABLISHMENT TYPE DESCRIPTION],
            (
            CASE
                WHEN a.[NHS_ESTABLISHMENT_IND] = '1'
                    THEN 'NHS'
                WHEN  a.[NHS_ESTABLISHMENT_IND] = '2'
                    THEN 'NON-NHS'
                ELSE 'OTHER'
            END) AS [NHS ESTABLISHMENT TYPE DESCRIPTION],
            (
            CASE
                WHEN a.[NHS_ESTABLISHMENT_IND] = '1'
                    THEN 'NHS'
                WHEN  a.[NHS_ESTABLISHMENT_IND] = '2'
                    THEN 'NON-NHS'
                ELSE 'OTHER'
            END) AS [NHS ESTABLISHMENT TYPE DESCRIPTION],
            (
            CASE
                WHEN a.PLACE_OF_DEATH_CODE = 'H'
                    THEN 'HOME'
                WHEN  a.PLACE_OF_DEATH_CODE = 'E'
                    THEN 'ELSEWHERE'
                ELSE 'OTHER'
            END
            ) AS [PLACE OF DEATH CODE],
            concat(a.[NHS_ESTABLISHMENT_IND],'-',a.PLACE_OF_DEATH_CODE) as code
FROM        RAW.dbo.ONS_Death_DOD201516FYQ1 AS a 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN REFERENCE.dbo.[ONS-PCMD_AGE] AS b 
                    ON a.CALCULATED_AGE_UNIT = b.[Age Unit] 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN REFERENCE.dbo.[OTH_ICD-10] AS c 
                    ON 
                        CASE 
                            WHEN LEN(
                                    CASE 
                                        WHEN (a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) = '' 
                                            THEN a.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
                                        WHEN (a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) IS NULL 
                                            THEN a.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
                                        ELSE a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH 
                                    END) = 3 
                            THEN CONCAT
                                (
                                    CASE 
                                        WHEN (a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) = '' 
                                            THEN a.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1]
                                        WHEN (a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) IS NULL
                                            THEN a.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
                                        ELSE a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH 
                                    END, 'X') 
                             ELSE (
                                    CASE 
                                        WHEN (a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) = '' 
                                            THEN a.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
                                        WHEN (a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) IS NULL 
                                            THEN a.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
                                        ELSE a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH 
                                    END) 
                        END = c.[4 CharacterDiagnosis Code]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN REFERENCE.dbo.GEOG_LANames_1991 AS d
                        ON a.[ULA_OF_RESIDENCE_CODE]    = d.[ONS_District_Code]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN REFERENCE.dbo.GEOG_WardNames_2014 AS e
                        ON CONCAT(ISNULL(a.[ULA_OF_RESIDENCE_CODE],''),ISNULL(a.[WARD_OF_RESIDENCE_CODE],'')) =e.WD14CDO
```

Comment: I got the following error message: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 125
Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: Thanks for persisting unfortunately still getting same error code

Comment: I have run the SQL again. It works fine in Query form but not in View form. Unfortunately, back to square 1. Thanks for your help

Comment: can you check whether the last line of the code is written properly .      ON CONCAT(ISNULL(a.[ULA_OF_RESIDENCE_CODE],''),ISNULL(a.[WARD_OF_RESIDENCE_CODE],'')) =e.WD14CDO

Comment: Fantastico! :) It worked. Please can you tell what you did as this is not the first time I have faced an error like this with CONCAT issue.

Comment: sure..consider concat (a,b) and say value for column a is null.. This will throw an error.. I simply checked whether your column a contains null value using is null function and replaced it with ''.  By the way mark it as a Right answer and an give a upvote .. :) that will increase my points..;):P

Comment: Done. Thanks. Those pesky null values.

Answer (score 0):

The **"CONCAT"** function must have **at least two parameters**.

However, in many places of your statement **you don't pass two parameters/columns to CONCATENATE**.

If you want to show `Fullname` from `Firstname` and `LastName`, you have to write:

```
CONCAT(Firstname, Lastname)
```

Comment: Does that mean it has to be declared in Select section?

Answer (score 0):

On MS SQL I got a similar "CONCAT needs 2 arguments" when I was trying to modify an existing view.

When I created a new view with the identical query, no problems there.
So some kind of cache issue can also be present.

Answer (score 0):

In MS SQL Server Management Studio, the {fn} is automatically added to views for CONCAT. I just used CONCAT_WS instead, which does not provoke this behavior. Added bonus: it does not add separators for NULL values.
The syntax is slightly different:

```
CONCAT_WS ( separator , argument1 , argument2 [ , argumentN ] ... )
```