# SQL works in Query form but not View form. Error: Concat function requires 2 arguments

Tags: sql, arguments, concatenation

I imagine the answer to this query is related to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39097937/error-message-concat-function-requires-2-arguments), however I am struggling.

Any help is much appreciated.

I am getting the following error message when running a piece of code.

The code works fine in Query form but not in view.

[image]

Code

```
SELECT 
CASE 
WHEN a.Sex = 1 
    THEN 'M' 
WHEN a.Sex = 2 
    THEN 'F' 
END AS Derived_Sex, 
CASE
WHEN concat(b.Complete, a.[CALCULATED_AGE]) LIKE 'A%' 
    THEN 'Less than 1' 
WHEN concat(b.Complete, a.[CALCULATED_AGE]) LIKE 'B%' 
    THEN 'Less than 1' 
WHEN concat(b.Complete, a.[CALCULATED_AGE]) LIKE 'C%' 
    THEN 'Less than 1' 
ELSE '1 year and above' 
END AS Derived_InfantCat,
concat(left(b.Complete,2),a.[CALCULATED_AGE],substring(b.Complete,3,100))  AS [Calculated Age],
YEAR(a.DATE_OF_DEATH) AS [Derived_Year of Death], 
FORMAT(a.DATE_OF_DEATH, 'MM') AS [Derived_Month of Death], 
YEAR(a.DATE_OF_REGISTRATION) AS [Derived_Year of Registration], 
FORMAT(a.DATE_OF_REGISTRATION, 'MM') AS [Derived_Month of Registration], 
CONCAT(LEFT(CONVERT(nvarchar, a.DATE_OF_DEATH, 21), 4), 
SUBSTRING(CONVERT(nvarchar, a.DATE_OF_DEATH, 21), 6, 2)) AS [Derived_YearMonth of Death], 
CONCAT(LEFT(CONVERT(nvarchar, a.DATE_OF_REGISTRATION, 21), 4), 
SUBSTRING(CONVERT(nvarchar, a.DATE_OF_REGISTRATION, 21), 6, 2)) AS [Derived_YearMonth of Registration], 
CASE 
WHEN LEN(
        CASE 
            WHEN (a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) = '' 
                THEN a.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
            WHEN (a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) IS NULL 
                THEN a.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
            ELSE a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH 
        END) = 3 
THEN CONCAT(
        CASE 
            WHEN (a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) = '' 
                THEN a.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
            WHEN (a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) IS NULL 
                THEN a.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
            ELSE a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH 
        END, 'X') 
ELSE 
        (CASE 
            WHEN (a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) = '' 
                THEN a.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
            WHEN (a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) IS NULL 
                THEN a.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
            ELSE a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH 
        END) 
END AS [Derived_Cause of Death Code], 
c.[4 character DESCRIPTION], 
c.[3 character Sub-Chapter Description], 
c.[Chapter Description],
d.[District_Name] AS [LA NAME],
e.[WD14NM] AS [WARD NAME],
a.[LSOA_OF_RESIDENCE_CODE] AS LSOA,
g.[Index of Multiple Deprivation (IMD) Score] AS [IMD 2015 Score],
g.[DERIVED_Havering Quintile (1 equals Most Deprived)] as [Havering Quintile],
(
CASE
WHEN a.[NHS_ESTABLISHMENT_IND] = '1'
    THEN 'NHS'
WHEN  a.[NHS_ESTABLISHMENT_IND] = '2'
    THEN 'NON-NHS'
ELSE 'OTHER'
END) AS [NHS ESTABLISHMENT TYPE DESCRIPTION],
(
CASE
WHEN a.PLACE_OF_DEATH_CODE = 'H'
    THEN 'HOME'
WHEN  a.PLACE_OF_DEATH_CODE = 'E'
    THEN 'ELSEWHERE'
ELSE 'OTHER'
END
) AS [PLACE OF DEATH CODE],
(
CASE
WHEN a.PLACE_OF_DEATH_CODE = 'H'
    THEN ''
WHEN  a.PLACE_OF_DEATH_CODE = 'E'
    THEN ''
ELSE concat(a.[NHS_ESTABLISHMENT_IND],'-',a.PLACE_OF_DEATH_ESTAB_TYPE) 
END
) AS [NHS ESTABLISHMENT CODE],
isnull(f.[Place of Death Establishment Type],a.PLACE_OF_DEATH_CODE) AS [PLACE OF DEATH ESTABLISHMENT TYPE]

FROM        RAW.dbo.ONS_Death AS a 
inner join  REFERENCE.dbo.[ONS-PCMD_AGE] AS b 
ON a.CALCULATED_AGE_UNIT = b.[Age Unit] 
left outer JOIN REFERENCE.dbo.[OTH_ICD-10] AS c 
    ON 
        CASE 
            WHEN LEN(
                    CASE 
                        WHEN (a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) = '' 
                            THEN a.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
                        WHEN (a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) IS NULL 
                            THEN a.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
                        ELSE a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH 
                    END) = 3 
            THEN CONCAT
                (
                    CASE 
                        WHEN (a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) = '' 
                            THEN a.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1]
                        WHEN (a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) IS NULL
                            THEN a.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
                        ELSE a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH 
                    END, 'X') 
                ELSE (
                    CASE 
                        WHEN (a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) = '' 
                            THEN a.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
                        WHEN (a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) IS NULL 
                            THEN a.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
                        ELSE a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH 
                    END) 
        END = c.[4 CharacterDiagnosis Code]
LEFT OUTER JOIN REFERENCE.dbo.GEOG_LANames_1991 AS d
        ON a.[ULA_OF_RESIDENCE_CODE]    = d.[ONS_District_Code]
LEFT OUTER JOIN REFERENCE.dbo.GEOG_WardNames_2014 AS e ON { fn CONCAT(ISNULL(a.ULA_OF_RESIDENCE_CODE, ''), ISNULL(a.WARD_OF_RESIDENCE_CODE, '')) } = e.WD14CDO
LEFT OUTER JOIN REFERENCE.[dbo].[GEOG_NHSCE_EstabTypes_2016] AS f 
ON 
    CASE 
        WHEN a.PLACE_OF_DEATH_CODE = 'H'
        THEN ''
        WHEN  a.PLACE_OF_DEATH_CODE = 'E'
        THEN ''
        ELSE {fn concat({ fn CONCAT(ISNUll(convert(nvarchar,a.[NHS_ESTABLISHMENT_IND],21),''),'-')},isnull(convert(nvarchar,a.PLACE_OF_DEATH_ESTAB_TYPE,21),''))} 
    END = f.[Code]
LEFT OUTER JOIN REFERENCE.[dbo].[OTH_IMD2015] AS g
    ON a.[LSOA_OF_RESIDENCE_CODE] = g.[LSOA code (2011)]
    order by [Calculated Age]
```

**The code above seems to prefix concatenate function with an {fn as shown below, if that helps anyone to solve this**

```
SELECT        
CASE    WHEN aPCMD.Sex = 1 THEN 'M' 
WHEN aPCMD.Sex = 2 THEN 'F'
ELSE 'unknown'
END AS Derived_Sex, 
CASE    WHEN concat(bAgeLookup.Complete, aPCMD.[CALCULATED_AGE]) LIKE 'A%' THEN 'Less than 1' 
WHEN concat(bAgeLookup.Complete, aPCMD.[CALCULATED_AGE]) LIKE 'B%' THEN 'Less than 1' 
WHEN concat(bAgeLookup.Complete, aPCMD.[CALCULATED_AGE]) LIKE 'C%' THEN 'Less than 1' 
ELSE '1 year and above' 
END AS Derived_InfantCat, 
{ fn CONCAT(LEFT(bAgeLookup.Complete, 2), aPCMD.CALCULATED_AGE, SUBSTRING(bAgeLookup.Complete, 3, 100)) } AS Derived_Age, 
YEAR(aPCMD.DATE_OF_DEATH) AS [Derived_Year of Death], 
FORMAT(aPCMD.DATE_OF_DEATH, 'MM') AS [Derived_Month of Death], 
YEAR(aPCMD.DATE_OF_REGISTRATION) AS [Derived_Year of Registration], 
FORMAT(aPCMD.DATE_OF_REGISTRATION, 'MM') AS [Derived_Month of Registration], 
              { fn CONCAT(LEFT(CONVERT(nvarchar, aPCMD.DATE_OF_DEATH, 21), 4), SUBSTRING(CONVERT(nvarchar, aPCMD.DATE_OF_DEATH, 21), 6, 2)) } AS [Derived_YearMonth of Death], 
{ fn CONCAT(LEFT(CONVERT(nvarchar,  aPCMD.DATE_OF_REGISTRATION, 21), 4), SUBSTRING(CONVERT(nvarchar, aPCMD.DATE_OF_REGISTRATION, 21), 6, 2)) } AS [Derived_YearMonth of Registration], 
CASE    WHEN LEN(
CASE    WHEN (aPCMD.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) = '' THEN aPCMD.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
WHEN (aPCMD.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) IS NULL THEN aPCMD.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
ELSE aPCMD.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH 
END) = 3 
THEN CONCAT(CASE    WHEN (aPCMD.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH)  = '' THEN aPCMD.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
WHEN (aPCMD.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) IS NULL THEN aPCMD.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
ELSE aPCMD.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH 
END, 'X') 
                            ELSE (CASE  WHEN (aPCMD.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) = '' 
THEN aPCMD.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] WHEN (aPCMD.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) IS NULL 
                            THEN aPCMD.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
ELSE aPCMD.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH 
END) 
END AS [Derived_Cause of Death Code], cICD10.[4 character DESCRIPTION] AS Derived, 
cICD10.[3 character Sub-Chapter Description], 
cICD10.[Chapter Description], 
d.District_Name AS [LA NAME], 
e.WD14NM AS [WARD NAME], 
aPCMD.LSOA_OF_RESIDENCE_CODE AS LSOA, 
g.[Index of Multiple Deprivation (IMD) Score] AS [IMD 2015 Score], 
g.[DERIVED_Havering Quintile (1 equals Most Deprived)] AS [Havering Quintile], 
 (CASE  WHEN aPCMD.[NHS_ESTABLISHMENT_IND] = '1' THEN 'NHS' 
WHEN aPCMD.[NHS_ESTABLISHMENT_IND] = '2' THEN 'NON-NHS' 
ELSE 'OTHER' 
END) AS [NHS ESTABLISHMENT TYPE DESCRIPTION], 
 (CASE  WHEN aPCMD.PLACE_OF_DEATH_CODE = 'H' THEN 'HOME' 
WHEN aPCMD.PLACE_OF_DEATH_CODE = 'E' 
THEN 'ELSEWHERE' 
ELSE 'OTHER' END) AS [PLACE OF DEATH CODE], 
 (CASE  WHEN aPCMD.PLACE_OF_DEATH_CODE = 'H' THEN '' 
WHEN aPCMD.PLACE_OF_DEATH_CODE = 'E' THEN '' 
ELSE concat(aPCMD.[NHS_ESTABLISHMENT_IND], '-', aPCMD.PLACE_OF_DEATH_ESTAB_TYPE) 
END) AS [NHS ESTABLISHMENT CODE], 
ISNULL(f.[Place of Death Establishment Type],
 aPCMD.PLACE_OF_DEATH_CODE) AS [PLACE OF DEATH ESTABLISHMENT TYPE]
 
FROM                RAW.dbo.ONS_Death AS aPCMD 
INNER JOIN  REFERENCE.dbo.[ONS-PCMD_AGE] AS bAgeLookup
ON aPCMD.CALCULATED_AGE_UNIT = bAgeLookup.[Age Unit] 

LEFT OUTER JOIN REFERENCE.dbo.[OTH_ICD-10] AS cICD10 
ON CASE WHEN LEN(
CASE    WHEN (aPCMD.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) = '' THEN aPCMD.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
WHEN (aPCMD.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) IS NULL THEN aPCMD.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
ELSE aPCMD.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH 
END) = 3 
THEN CONCAT(    CASE    WHEN (aPCMD.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH)  = '' THEN aPCMD.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
WHEN (aPCMD.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) IS NULL THEN aPCMD.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
ELSE aPCMD.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH 
END, 'X') 
                                    ELSE (CASE  WHEN (aPCMD.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) = '' THEN aPCMD.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
WHEN (aPCMD.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) IS NULL THEN aPCMD.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
ELSE aPCMD.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH 
END) 
END = cICD10.[4 CharacterDiagnosis Code] 

LEFT OUTER JOIN REFERENCE.dbo.GEOG_LANames_1991 AS d 
ON aPCMD.ULA_OF_RESIDENCE_CODE = d.ONS_District_Code 

LEFT OUTER JOIN REFERENCE.dbo.GEOG_WardNames_2014 AS e 
ON { fn CONCAT(ISNULL(aPCMD.ULA_OF_RESIDENCE_CODE, ''), ISNULL(aPCMD.WARD_OF_RESIDENCE_CODE, '')) } = e.WD14CDO 

 
LEFT OUTER JOIN REFERENCE.dbo.GEOG_NHSCE_EstabTypes_2016 AS f
ON CASE     WHEN aPCMD.PLACE_OF_DEATH_CODE = 'H' THEN '' 
WHEN aPCMD.PLACE_OF_DEATH_CODE = 'E' THEN '' 
ELSE { fn concat({ fn CONCAT(ISNUll(CONVERT(nvarchar, aPCMD.[NHS_ESTABLISHMENT_IND], 21), ''), '-') }, 
                                        isnull(CONVERT(nvarchar, aPCMD.PLACE_OF_DEATH_ESTAB_TYPE, 21), '')) } 
END = f.Code 

LEFT OUTER JOIN REFERENCE.dbo.OTH_IMD2015 AS g ON aPCMD.LSOA_OF_RESIDENCE_CODE = g.[LSOA code (2011)]
```

Comment: Minimize the query. Too much to read.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below code..

```
SELECT 
CASE 
WHEN a.Sex = 1 
    THEN 'M' 
WHEN a.Sex = 2 
    THEN 'F' 
END AS Derived_Sex, 
CASE
WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(b.Complete,'')+ ISNULL(a.[CALCULATED_AGE],''))) LIKE 'A%'
    THEN 'Less than 1' 
WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(b.Complete,'')+ ISNULL(a.[CALCULATED_AGE],''))) LIKE 'B%' 
    THEN 'Less than 1' 
WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(b.Complete,'')+ISNULL(a.[CALCULATED_AGE],''))) LIKE 'C%' 
    THEN 'Less than 1' 
ELSE '1 year and above' 
END AS Derived_InfantCat,
left(ISNULL(b.Complete,''),2)+ISNULL(a.[CALCULATED_AGE],'')+substring(ISNULL(b.Complete,''),3,100)  AS [Calculated Age],
YEAR(a.DATE_OF_DEATH) AS [Derived_Year of Death], 
FORMAT(a.DATE_OF_DEATH, 'MM') AS [Derived_Month of Death], 
YEAR(a.DATE_OF_REGISTRATION) AS [Derived_Year of Registration], 
FORMAT(a.DATE_OF_REGISTRATION, 'MM') AS [Derived_Month of Registration], 
ISNULL(LEFT(CONVERT(nvarchar, a.DATE_OF_DEATH, 21), 4),'')+ 
ISNULL(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(nvarchar, a.DATE_OF_DEATH, 21), 6, 2),'') AS [Derived_YearMonth of Death], 
ISNULL(LEFT(CONVERT(nvarchar, a.DATE_OF_REGISTRATION, 21), 4),'')+
ISNULL(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(nvarchar, a.DATE_OF_REGISTRATION, 21), 6, 2),'') AS [Derived_YearMonth of Registration], 
CASE 
WHEN LEN(
        CASE 
            WHEN (a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) = '' 
                THEN a.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
            WHEN (a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) IS NULL 
                THEN a.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
            ELSE a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH 
        END) = 3 
THEN CASE 
            WHEN (a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) = '' 
                THEN ISNULL(a.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1],'') 
            WHEN (a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) IS NULL 
                THEN ISNULL(a.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1],'') 
            ELSE ISNULL(a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH,'') 
        END+ 'X'
ELSE 
        (CASE 
            WHEN (a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) = '' 
                THEN a.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
            WHEN (a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) IS NULL 
                THEN a.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
            ELSE a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH 
        END) 
END AS [Derived_Cause of Death Code], 
c.[4 character DESCRIPTION], 
c.[3 character Sub-Chapter Description], 
c.[Chapter Description],
d.[District_Name] AS [LA NAME],
e.[WD14NM] AS [WARD NAME],
a.[LSOA_OF_RESIDENCE_CODE] AS LSOA,
g.[Index of Multiple Deprivation (IMD) Score] AS [IMD 2015 Score],
g.[DERIVED_Havering Quintile (1 equals Most Deprived)] as [Havering Quintile],
(
CASE
WHEN a.[NHS_ESTABLISHMENT_IND] = '1'
    THEN 'NHS'
WHEN  a.[NHS_ESTABLISHMENT_IND] = '2'
    THEN 'NON-NHS'
ELSE 'OTHER'
END) AS [NHS ESTABLISHMENT TYPE DESCRIPTION],
(
CASE
WHEN a.PLACE_OF_DEATH_CODE = 'H'
    THEN 'HOME'
WHEN  a.PLACE_OF_DEATH_CODE = 'E'
    THEN 'ELSEWHERE'
ELSE 'OTHER'
END
) AS [PLACE OF DEATH CODE],
(
CASE
WHEN a.PLACE_OF_DEATH_CODE = 'H'
    THEN ''
WHEN  a.PLACE_OF_DEATH_CODE = 'E'
    THEN ''
ELSE ISNULL(a.[NHS_ESTABLISHMENT_IND],'')+'-'+ISNULL(a.PLACE_OF_DEATH_ESTAB_TYPE,'')
END
) AS [NHS ESTABLISHMENT CODE],
isnull(f.[Place of Death Establishment Type],a.PLACE_OF_DEATH_CODE) AS [PLACE OF DEATH ESTABLISHMENT TYPE]

FROM        RAW.dbo.ONS_Death AS a 
inner join  REFERENCE.dbo.[ONS-PCMD_AGE] AS b 
ON a.CALCULATED_AGE_UNIT = b.[Age Unit] 
left outer JOIN REFERENCE.dbo.[OTH_ICD-10] AS c 
    ON 
        CASE 
            WHEN LEN(
                    CASE 
                        WHEN (a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) = '' 
                            THEN a.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
                        WHEN (a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) IS NULL 
                            THEN a.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
                        ELSE a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH 
                    END) = 3 
            THEN  CASE 
                        WHEN (a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) = '' 
                            THEN ISNULL(a.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1],'')
                        WHEN (a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) IS NULL
                            THEN ISNULL(a.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1],'') 
                        ELSE ISNULL(a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH,'') 
                    END+ 'X' 
                ELSE (
                    CASE 
                        WHEN (a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) = '' 
                            THEN a.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
                        WHEN (a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH) IS NULL 
                            THEN a.[CAUSE_OF_DEATH_ICD_CODE_1] 
                        ELSE a.UNDERLYING_CAUSE_OF_DEATH 
                    END) 
        END = c.[4 CharacterDiagnosis Code]
LEFT OUTER JOIN REFERENCE.dbo.GEOG_LANames_1991 AS d
        ON a.[ULA_OF_RESIDENCE_CODE]    = d.[ONS_District_Code]
LEFT OUTER JOIN REFERENCE.dbo.GEOG_WardNames_2014 AS e ON ISNULL(a.ULA_OF_RESIDENCE_CODE, '')+ ISNULL(a.WARD_OF_RESIDENCE_CODE, '') = e.WD14CDO
LEFT OUTER JOIN REFERENCE.[dbo].[GEOG_NHSCE_EstabTypes_2016] AS f 
ON 
    CASE 
        WHEN a.PLACE_OF_DEATH_CODE = 'H'
        THEN ''
        WHEN  a.PLACE_OF_DEATH_CODE = 'E'
        THEN ''
        ELSE ISNUll(convert(nvarchar,a.[NHS_ESTABLISHMENT_IND],21),'')+'-'+isnull(convert(nvarchar,a.PLACE_OF_DEATH_ESTAB_TYPE,21),'')
    END = f.[Code]
LEFT OUTER JOIN REFERENCE.[dbo].[OTH_IMD2015] AS g
    ON a.[LSOA_OF_RESIDENCE_CODE] = g.[LSOA code (2011)]
  ORDER BY [Calculated Age]
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back. Still same error unfortunately.

Comment: Anyone able to have a look

Comment: Unfortunately, still not working... Thanks for trying

Comment: Still trying, can anyone hep with this?

Comment: I have replaced the CONCAT function with + operator. can you try once again with the updated code and let me know the status.

Comment: Thanks for persisting. Unfortunately, different error this type saying error converting nvarchar to float.